# PowerShell variables look equal but comparisons say they are not

Tags: powershell

I have an auto download that pulls files from an FTP site into 2 separate folders. I am trying to write a script that will extract the common portion of the file names and then compare them to see if the 2 directories contain the same file names.

I wrote this and when I check the variables with Get-Variable file(#) -ValueOnly , $file1 and $file4 show the same results. However the email I get is the one that says they are not equal.

The files in the 1st path look like  *(name)*_QM_20230301.xml
The files in the 2nd path look like  Batchfile_*(name)*_03-01-2023_03-01-2023.zip

```
$file1 = [string[]](Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Data\folder1) -replace '_.*\.*'

$File2 = [string[]](Get-childItem -Path C:\Temp\Data\dwnld)
$split = $File2.Split("_")
$file4 = $split[1] ,$split[6], $split[11] -replace '_.*\.*'

If ($file1 -eq $file4) {Send-MailMessage -to someone@domain.com -subject "FTP Files" -from     Admin@domain.com -body "The FTP files match" -smtpserver 10.0.0.xxx}
If ($file1 -ne $file4) {Send-MailMessage -to someone@domain.com -subject "FTP Files" -from Admin@domain.com -body "The FTP files do not match" -smtpserver 10.0.0.xxx}
```

I am sure it is obvious I am new to writing power shell scripts, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're attempting to compare _all the files_ in the first directory with _all the files_ in the second. `-eq` and `-ne` can't do that. You'll need to loop through one collection of file names and then attempt to find the corresponding file name in the second collection, and so on, etc.

Comment: Thank you -- that is so much easier and elegant that what i was understanding I needed to do!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `ForEach-Object` to extract the document name only, from each file, 1 at a time:

```
$list1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Data\folder1 |ForEach-Object { $_.Name.Split('_')[0] }
$list2 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\Data\dwnld |ForEach-Object { $_.Name.Split('_')[1] }
```

Now that both lists contain just the substring that needs to be compared, we can use `Compare-Object` to see if any differences occur:

```
$message = if(Compare-Object $list1 $list2) {
    "FTP files differ"
}
else {
    "FTP files are the same"
}
Send-MailMessage -To someone@domain.com -Subject "FTP Files" -From Admin@domain.com -Body $message -SmtpServer 10.0.0.xxx
```